# How to get sequence of numbers and then print the last 5?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, integer

Im trying to make a program that will get sequence from the user that end with 0, and then i want to print the last 5 numbers (not including the 0).

I can assume that the user will input all the numbers in one line and will end it with 0.

I wrote that code but something is wrong with it, I think its something about the scanf line.

Input:

```
1 6 9 5 2 1 4 3 0
```

Output: no output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

int main()
{
    int arr[N] = {0};
    int last_input, j;
    
    printf("please enter more than %d number and than enter 0: \n", N);
    
    last_input = 0;
    while (last_input<N) {
       scanf(" %d", &j);
       if (j == '0') {
          last_input = N;
          break;
       }
       else {
          arr[last_input] = j;
       }
       if (last_input==(N-1)) {
          last_input=-1;
       }
       ++last_input;
   }
    
    
    printf("The last %d numbers u entered are:\n", N); 
    
    for (j=(last_input+1); j<N; ++j) {
       printf(" %d", arr[j]);    
    }

    for (j=0; j<last_input; ++j) {
       printf(" %d", arr[j]);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, the test `if (j == '0')` is wrong.  You're comparing to the *character* `'0'`.  You want to compare to the *integer* 0: `if (j == 0)`.

Comment: Can you give us an I/O example?

Comment: @Roi yes sure. input "1 6 9 5 2 1 4 3 0", output - there is no output. I will edit my question too. ty

Comment: @SteveSummit So I changed the code but now for the input 1 6 9 5 2 1 4 3 0 the output is 1 4 3 5 2. its the 5 last numbers but not in the original order.

Comment: @AlfaHores That's interesting!  I tried your code on the input `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0`, and it gave `6 7 8 9 10`, which looks right.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think the problem now is with the line last_input = N;.

Comment: how do u put line in gray color btw?

Comment: Always check the value returned by `scanf`.  In this case, that is as simple as `while( scanf(...) == 1`.  Your current `while` loop seems meaningless, since you are using the ring buffer to ensure that `last_input < N` is always true.

Comment: @AlfaHores: Put backticks (`\`codehere\``) around the code snippet (you can use backslashes to escape the backticks themselves, which is how I made that demonstration).

Comment: @AlfaHores Note: space character not needed in format for `scanf(" %d", &j);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comparison

```
if (j == '0') {
```

does not make a sense because the user will try to enter the integer value 0 instead of the value (for example ASCII 30h or EBCDIC F0h) for the character '0'.

You need to write at least

```
if (j == 0) {
```

Due to these sub-statements of the if statement

```
  last_input = N;
  break;
```

this for loop

```
for (j=(last_input+1); j<N; ++j) {
   printf(" %d", arr[j]);    
}
```

is never executed and does not make a sense.

This statement

```
last_input=-1;
```

results in breaking the order of the N last elements in its output. And moreover the result value of the variable `last_input` will be incorrect.

You need to move elements of the array one position left. For this purpose you can use a loop of standard C function memmove.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    int arr[N];

    printf( "Please enter at least not less than %d numbers (0 - stop): ", N );

    size_t count = 0;

    for (int num; scanf( "%d", &num ) == 1 && num != 0; )
    {
        if (count != N)
        {
            arr[count++] = num;
        }
        else
        {
            memmove( arr, arr + 1, ( N - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
            arr[N - 1] = num;
        }
    }

    if (count != 0)
    {
        printf( "The last %zu numbers u entered are: ", count );
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "There are no entered numbers." );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter at least not less than 5 numbers (0 - stop): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
The last 5 numbers u entered are: 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes based on ur comments and now its work fine!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

int main()
{
    int arr[N] = {0};
    int last_input, j;
    
    printf("please enter more than %d number and than enter 0: \n", N);
    
    last_input = 0;
    while (last_input<N) {
       scanf("%d", &j);
       if (j == 0) {
          break;
       }
       else {
          arr[last_input] = j;
       }
       if (last_input==(N-1)) {
          last_input=-1;
       }
       ++last_input;
   }
    
    
    printf("The last %d numbers u entered are:\n", N); 
    
    for (j=(last_input); j<N; ++j) {
       printf("%d ", arr[j]);    
    }

    for (j=0; j<last_input; ++j) {
       printf("%d ", arr[j]);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thank u guys <3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @lemon I saw the article but didnt understand what wrong. maybe I didnt write what did I changed? if this is the problem I will edit. i can delete the answer too if needed...